# Setting excel column styles in python (xlwt)

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm trying to write data to an excel document, some of the columns consist entirely of date/numeric data that I want to format. I could set a format on each cell individually, but that seems excessive. There's a `set_style` method on the column, object, but for some reason it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
import xlwt
from datetime import date
book = xlwt.Workbook('ascii')
sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1')
# cells in first column, they end up with no formatting
sheet.write(0, 0, date(2012, 1, 1))
sheet.write(1, 0, date(2012, 1, 1))
sheet.write(2, 0, date(2012, 2, 1))
style = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='YYYY-MM-DD')
sheet.col(0).set_style(style)
# cells in second column are formatted correctly
sheet.write(0, 1, date(2012, 1, 1), style)
sheet.write(1, 1, date(2012, 1, 1), style)
sheet.write(2, 1, date(2012, 2, 1), style)
book.save(open('foo.xls', 'wb'))
```

Comment: Just in case Vivek's answer gets deleted for being link-only: here's [the link he posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/python-excel/V4AVzPjsdrw) that trick said was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this could help:
[Similar to your question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/python-excel/V4AVzPjsdrw)

I have seen this used in loops, for efficient usage.

Comment: That helps. As it turns out that you can't really set column styles in XSL files in the way one would expect.

The problem I was running into was having too many styles, but it turns out that the cell styles are just references, so if you pass the same style object to different cell, you won't pass the style limit.

Comment: I found this question via Google. I'll upvote your answer if you edit it to answer the question rather than being link-only.